# Mapping of a curve-object

Tags: uv

I have a curve-object with some geometry-settings that I want to put on another curve.

[image: 01]

I'm setting up the scale of the mapping with generated texture coordinates until it's right. But if I activate the curve-modifier (+array) the mapping is not as I need it because it's not following the objects shape.

[image: 02]
[image: 03]
[image: 04]

So I'm changing the texture coordinates to UV and setup the scaling again. That looks better but the middle section is still problematic and I can't really setup the UVs for all sides properly as long as the extrude-value is more the 0. The last image has a very high y-value but that messes up the other sides.

[image: 05]
[image: 06]
[image: 08]

How can I map that middle section without converting it to a mesh? I want to have full control and easy access of the shape of the object. And of course a proper mapping.

[image]

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can't avoid converting your object into a mesh, and creating a *UV Map*.

You can do this as follows:

1. Convert your object into a mesh.

   [image: Convert to Mesh]
2. Then switch to *Edit Mode* and select a long edge (with *Select Edge Loop*). Mark this as *Mark Seam*. This is your cut line for the UVMap.

   [image: Mark Seams]
3. Select the whole object with <kbd>A</kbd> and choose *UV -> Unwrap* from the menu.

   [image: Unwrap Mesh]
4. Then switch to *UV Editing* and select a horizontal edge of a larger area. Then select *Align Y* to make it exactly horizontal. Repeat this with the lower edge of the face.

   [image: Align Y]
5. Do the same with the vertical edges of the face, but select *Align X*. This way you get a face that has exactly horizontal and vertical edges.

   [image: Align X]
6. Next, change the *UV Select Mode* to *Faces* and mark all other faces with <kbd>A</kbd> in addition to the previously edited face. Then select *Follow Active Quads* from the menu. This will align all faces exactly like the selected face.

   [image: Follow Active Quads]
7. After that you only need to insert the node `Texture Coordinate` in the shader and use the output *UV* as a vector.

   [image: Shade with UVMap]